# How to properly use EnableThemeDialogTexture()?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, mfc, dialog

My problem is regarding the look and feel of my dialog.

First, I enabled this source code on stdafx.h:

```
//#ifdef _UNICODE
#if defined _M_IX86
#pragma comment(linker,"/manifestdependency:\"type='win32' name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' processorArchitecture='x86' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'\"")
#elif defined _M_X64
#pragma comment(linker,"/manifestdependency:\"type='win32' name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' processorArchitecture='amd64' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'\"")
#else
#pragma comment(linker,"/manifestdependency:\"type='win32' name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' processorArchitecture='*' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'\"")
#endif
//#endif
```

Then, on my problematic dialog's `OnInitDialog()`, I added this:

```
#include "Uxtheme.h"

if (IsAppThemed())
{
    EnableThemeDialogTexture(*this, ETDT_ENABLETAB);
}
```

The purpose of this is to theme also the CTabCtrl on my dialog.

Now, when I build the project, it shows error:

```
LNK2001 unresolved extenal symbol __imp__IsAppThemed@0
LNK2001 unresolved extenal symbol __imp__EnableThemeDialogTexture@8
```

What other things am I missing for this "theming" to properly work?

Comment: Documentation for `IsAppThemed` shows that it needs `UxTheme.lib`. Add the library in project manager, or add this in any file `#pragma comment(lib, "UxTheme.lib")`

Comment: @BarmakShemirani thanks for pointing out `#pragma comment`. I didn't know before that aside from `#include` there needs to be something else to "include" the external library. Thanks again!

Comment: You are welcome. By the way `#pragma comment...` is specific to Visual Studio. I think `EnableThemeDialogTexture` applies to Windows XP only, XP is no longer supported by Microsoft.